# Getting error like module not found, some one please explain what type of error it is

Tags: angularjs

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module secReportWrapper due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module btford.socket-io due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'btford.socket-io' is not available! You ei......2)

Comment: You should write sentences for ask quetions.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the non-minified version of the AngularJS JavaScript File. As far as I know the error message then becomes clickable in your Console (e.g. Chrome Dev Tools, accessible by pressing F12) and leads to a more detailed error description in the Angular API docs. Also the message is then not truncated like it seems to be in your posting above.
From what is readable of the error message it looks like you may have forgotten to include (script tag with src attribute) the js File containing the module "btford.socket-io". If it is included the it might have something to do with the order of your "includes" i.e. script tags.

In your "question", where it says "You ei...2)" I assume it continues to say "You either misspelled...", so also check for typos

a) in your index.html file (or whatever you called the HTML file which loads all the JavaScript)
b) where you declare your apps dependencies...that is the part of your code where you have sth. like:

```
angular.module('NameOfYourApp',['dependency1', 'dependency2','...']);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you didn't included socket.io from Mr Ford which can be found here
https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io

Answer (score 0):

When I run into this error the problem was a missing closing bracket of the script tag used to include btford.socket-io in index.html.

I think html syntax error detector should jump in first and then angular'.
Hope it saves someone's time before they dig deeper and overthink it :)